# Sprite Batch concept

Tags: c++, directx-11

I would like to confirm the following, Is it fine to use just one sprite-batch and draw it fonts, and other animated sprites ? if that's true, how many quads that can be batched using just one sprite-batch?is that an issue of DirectX API and it takes care of that or GPU ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is ok to use one sprite batch object for fonts and other sprites. In fact it is probably better that way.

The number of sprites that can be batched is up to the implementation. If you are using the `SpriteBatch` class in the DirectXTK, then it uses a growing array as you add sprites to it so there is no real limit to the number of sprites you can give it (except for memory). Internally it creates a vertex buffer that can handle 2048 sprites or 2048*4 vertices.  This doesn't limit the amount of sprites that you can send to the `SpriteBatch`. It just means that if you queue up 3000 sprites for example, it will need to make at least two draw calls to render everything (more if you are using multiple textures).

So, the number of sprites that can be drawn in one call depends on the size of the vertex buffer that the implementation has created. The maximum size of a vertex buffer ultimately depends on how much memory is available.

Comment: Note _DirectX Tool Kit_ can be found on [CodePlex](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) along with documentation for [SpriteBatch](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SpriteBatch&referringTitle=DirectXTK) and [SpriteFont](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SpriteFont&referringTitle=DirectXTK).